# JavaFX Value in thumb of slider

Tags: css, javafx, binding, integer, slider

I have a slider here that displays a number on the slider thumb. Whenever I drag the slider, the number increments or decrements. I want the thumb to display an integer instead of a double.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SliderWithLabeledThumb extends Application {
    public void start(Stage ps) {
        Slider s = new Slider();

        StackPane root = new StackPane(s);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        s.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        s.setMin(49);
        s.setMax(99);
        s.setValue(51);
        s.setMinorTickCount(0);
        s.setMajorTickUnit(1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        s.applyCss();
        s.layout();
        Pane p = (Pane) s.lookup(".thumb");
        Label l = new Label();
        l.textProperty().bind(s.valueProperty().asString("%.1f").concat(" °"));

        p.getChildren().add(l);

        ps.setScene(scene);
        ps.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I change the argument for asString() from "%.1f" to a "%d", I get an exception

```
l.textProperty().bind(s.valueProperty().asString("%d").concat(" °"));
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.StringFormatter$4.computeValue(StringFormatter.java:196)
    at javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding.get(StringBinding.java:152)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.StringFormatter.format(StringFormatter.java:207)
    at javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.format(Bindings.java:4846)
    at javafx.beans.binding.NumberExpressionBase.asString(NumberExpressionBase.java:319)
    at embeddedwebview.SliderWithLabeledThumb.start(SliderWithLabeledThumb.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Here is my CSS File:

```
.slider .track {
    -fx-pref-height: 10px;
    -fx-pref-width: 20px;
}

.slider .thumb {
    -fx-pref-height: 30;
    -fx-prefer-width: 30;
}
```

Current output so far:

[image: slider]

Comment: Maybe something similar to this situation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681664/javafx-slider-integer-only Or do you only want the display value as an int but the actual value as a double?

Comment: What happend when you use `%.0f`?

Comment: You have a minor typo in your css: `-fx-prefer-width: 30;` should be `-fx-pref-width: 30;`

Comment: Thanks guys! You tips really helped!

Answer (score 2):

This question ends up being pretty much a duplicate of:

- [Problem with System.out.printf command in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693079/problem-with-system-out-printf-command-in-java)

So you can't use `%d` to format a double value, you must use `%f`.  If you only want to display the integer portion of the double value, you can let `%.0f` (as recommended in comments by Hypnic Jerk) do the rounding to zero decimal places (the decimal point will not be displayed).  According to the [formatting javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), the [round half up algorithm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_UP) is used.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SliderWithLabeledThumb extends Application {
    public void start(Stage ps) {
        Slider s = new Slider();

        StackPane root = new StackPane(s);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        s.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        s.setMin(49);
        s.setMax(99);
        s.setValue(51);
        s.setMinorTickCount(0);
        s.setMajorTickUnit(1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        s.applyCss();
        s.layout();
        Pane p = (Pane) s.lookup(".thumb");
        Label l = new Label();
        l.textProperty().bind(s.valueProperty().asString("%.0f").concat(" °"));

        p.getChildren().add(l);

        ps.setScene(scene);
        ps.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: round]